# How to calculate the Force between a magnet & an induced dipole?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction, superconductivity, magnetic-moment

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xTwDZJG_W9w

In this video at 9:12 it details the potential energy of an induced dipole

Specifically
$$U=-mBcos\theta=(\frac{\chi V}{\mu_0}B)Bcos\theta$$
&
$$F_z=\frac{3\mu_0\chi V m_m}{2\pi^2}\frac{1}{z^7}$$

1. What would the full derivation be to get the power of 7 fall off?
2. Is this accurate for most cases?
3. Example: If I had a copper bullet(spherical musket like) travelling at a powerful spherical neodymium magnet; would I just use the $U$ & $F_z$ against the Newtonian $F=ma$ & $K_e=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ respectively?
4. The Force is simply the 2 magnetic moments multiplied together with a 7th power fall off?(just looking for confirmation for the simplification)
5. Stability regions are defined as $$F=0=F_{gravitational}+F_{kinetic}-F_{diamagnetic/superconductive}$$ ?
6. Are these equations valid for Km scales? Even thousands of Km?(Car scale to planet/star scale)
7. Can I use these equations to plot the positions of diamagnetic objects vs magnetic objects in space in a similar fashion to the gravitational & kinetic equations?(or are there better equations for that?)

https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/10.1119/1.16700